# how to maintain specific version for embedded web view across different devices?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-settings, android-websettings, android-chrome

We have embedded web view using webkit in our app.

> implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0'

But when we install this app in different devices (mobile, android boxes, android tv's) the webview versions are showing different in different devices.

Is there any way to force the app use specific version of webview?
We are facing some issues with older versions. So is there any way to maintain this version latest?

Please suggest possible ways to maintain the webview version fixed.

Comment: `androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0` uses the system webview and enables a Chrome specific feature [Custom Tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs/integration-guide/). Normally the system webview updated via Google Play Store. You might want to provide more info on what is failing and if you are using Chrome specific features.

Comment: ok, i understand that `androidx.browser` uses system webview & this can be updated via Google play store only. thanks @MorrisonChang.

Is there any way we can use a specific version of webview? My requirement is to push my app to use same version of webview across all devices.

Comment: The only way to force to use the same webview is to package one in your app. Otherwise you are limited by the device updates. As that is non-trivial (and makes your app larger) you would be better off figuring out why different things are being shown. You don't mention how old the older versions are and it may be that the hardware/software on those devices are no longer supported or can handle the new HTML5 features. If this is for a Play Store app see: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2021/07/google-play-services-discontinuing-jelly-bean.html

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving this is to package a WebView implementation in your app. This increases the bundle, but it might be worth it if you want to support very old devices or if adjusting your web content to previous Chromium versions is hard.

As of now, there is only one available WebView package I know of: [GeckoView](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/GeckoView) by Mozilla. It's the engine that powers the FireFox browser. From my tests, it adds about 50-60 MB to your app's bundle size.

BTW, according to [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/yli0gh/is_geckoview_a_solid_alternative_for_when_you/), your users might be unable to use it without rooting their device.